# Difference between GTO and BJT

Tags: power-electronics, bjt

What is the main difference between the GTO and BJT in terms of advantages/disadvantages from a power electronics point of view ?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What did your text book/google search reveal and where are you stuck?

Comment: "Please explain all of physics in 100 words or less".  Could you try to make your question more specific?  Perhaps refer to a specific application where you know that a GTO or as BJT is used, and ask why?

Comment: Does anyone even *use* GTO thyristors anymore? They're such a pain.

Answer (score 3):

The difference from a power point of view is that the GTO (two literal united didodes) is designed for that, only with one pulse you activate it and the BJT (Two diodes that share a region) you have to find the right one for power and requires a constant current in the base to work.